# Invalid session id in specflow Selenium on closing [AfterScenarios]

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I am opening a browser session at [BeginScenario] and Quit the session at the [AfterScenario].
At the beginning of second scenario, i am getting 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'invalid session id'.
How do we start a new session at the beginning of each scenario.?

```
[Binding]
public class BasePage
{
    public static IWebDriver driver;

    public static void BrowserSetup()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();               
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }
}

[Binding]
public class Hook : BasePage
{
    [BeforeScenario]
    public void Initialize(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        BrowserSetup(); // Initialise the driver from BaseClass
        scenario = featureName.CreateNode<Scenario>(scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
        //scenario = featureName.CreateNode<Scenario>(scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void CleanUp(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        if (scenarioContext.TestError != null)
        {
            TakeScreenshot(driver);
        }
        //driver.Close();
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running tests in parallel?

Comment: No. Single browser. Each time a new scenario starts from login page, the old session  data is retained and it fails my test.So i was trying to close the browser session before each scenario. Using quit(), the session closes but it doesnt open a new one in BeforeScenario. ->BrowserSetup();

Comment: Which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver are you using?

Comment: Are your sure the exception is being caused by the Hook class? Can you post the stack trace?